# css table column and row highlight on hover not working

Tags: css, html-table

Im using a modified version of this: https://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/rUhCa/ to highlight the row and column of a table on mouse over in pure css

Mine is slightly more complicated as some of the table cell backgrounds are painted different colours depending on their contents (done by editing the bg colour directly on the 'td' element).

The highlighting works fine but due to the z-levels the cells with the 'td' background colour appear 'above' the highlighting, and I want it to appear below - If I set the z-levels to a positive number I can achieve this effect however this then breaks the ability to change the highlight by moving the mouse in cells that are already highlighted

html:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th class="col">50kg</th>
        <th class="col">55kg</th>
        <th class="col">60kg</th>
        <th class="col">65kg</th>
        <th class="col">70kg</th>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="row">160cm</th>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td bgcolor="yellow">25</td>
        <td bgcolor="yellow">27</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="row">165cm</th>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td bgcolor="yellow">22</td>
        <td>24</td>
        <td>26</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="row">170cm</th>
        <td bgcolor="yellow">17</td>
        <td>19</td>
        <td>21</td>
        <td>23</td>
        <td>25</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <th class="row">175cm</th>
        <td>16</td>
        <td>18</td>
        <td>20</td>
        <td>22</td>
        <td>24</td>
    </tr>

</table>
```

css

```
table {
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: -5;
}
table th { 
    color:white;
    background-color:#404040;
    padding: 8px;
    width: 50px;
}
table td { 
    color: #1a3640;
    border-radius: 3px;
}
table td,table th,table .row,table .col { 
    cursor: pointer;
    position: relative;
}
table td:hover::before,table .row:hover::before { 
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 100%;
    left: -300vh;
    position: absolute;  
    top: 0;
    width: 300vw;   
    z-index: -1;        
}
table td:hover::after,table .col:hover::after { 
    background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.5);
    content: '\00a0';  
    height: 300vw;    
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;  
    top: -300vh;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: -1;        
}
```

Comment: Please provide a proper [mre] of your issue, directly inside the question.

Comment: Please don't tack an edit onto the bottom of your question which changes the nature of everything above. Rewrite the whole question so it's clear from the start. Don't annotate edits.

Answer (score 1):

Disable pointer events on those pseudo elements with `pointer-events: none;`

Comment: sorry, I dont understand, which elements?

Comment: @Brick the `::before` and `::after` pseudo elements, like this: `z-index: 1; pointer-events: none;`